# How to convert a string into float such as '6.1' to 6.01 and '6.10' to 6.10?

Tags: python

I have script that scraps version data which is in string.

Example string data:

```
data1 = '6.10'

data2 = '6.1'
```

Is there a way to convert in such a way like

```
data1 = float(data1)  # -> 6.10

data2 = float(data2)  # -> 6.01 or 6.1
```

below are the real scenario that im working on, **notice 7.10 ≠ 7.1.**

```
7.16 (EOL date: 31 August 2023)
7.15 (EOL date: 27 July 2023)
7.14 (EOL date: 22 June 2023)
7.13 (EOL date: 18 May 2023)
7.12 (EOL date: 13 April 2023)
7.11 (EOL date: 10 March 2023)
7.10 (EOL date: 02 February 2023)
7.9 (EOL date: 05 January 2023)
7.8 (EOL date: 24 November 2022)
7.7 (EOL date: 22 October 2022)
7.6 (EOL date: 15 September 2022)
7.5 (EOL date: 11 August 2022)
7.4 (EOL date: 09 July 2022)
7.3 (EOL date: 02 June 2022)
7.2 (EOL date: 28 April 2022)
7.1 (EOL date: 24 March 2022)
7.0 (EOL date: 5 March 2022)
6.10 (EOL date: 14 January 2022)
6.9 (EOL date: 10 December 2021)
6.8 (EOL date: 6 November 2021)
6.7 (EOL date: 1 October 2021)
```

Comment: This makes no sense: 6.1 ≠ 6.01! Convesely, 6.1 = 6.10!

Comment: `float` _is_ how, but neither `'6.10'` nor `'6.1'` parses to `6.01`.

Comment: I think what you have is a sequence of digits with a `.` in it, and you're confusing that with a float, which is a numerical value.

Comment: Comparing version numbers reliably is really tricky business. Not using `float` is the first step. It's usually a reasonable idea to parse version numbers into an arbitrary amount of components (`1.0` has two components, `0.0.2` has 3, `3.1.4-14` has 4) and then compare each of them in some defined way (you might get away to compare them numerically, if no one introduces `0.1-alpha1`, then things become weird).

Answer (score 1):

The real data isn't a float number but a pair of two numbers
you can use a `tuple` to hold that pair after splitting the input string

```
split_line = line.split(" ")
data_tuple = tuple([int x for x in split_line[0].split(".")])
```

Using a `tuple` lets you compare the numbers, but the number of operations is limited (you can use `==` but not arithmetics)

---

To convert the from string to float, just use `float()`

```
data1 = '6.01'
data1_float = float(data1)
```

The number is represented as float in memory, and when you print it you can choose how many digits to print with.

In python 3 you can use formatting strings and set the exact number of decimal digits:

```
f"{data1:.2f}"
```

In the real scenario, assuming you read the data line by line, you can split the line with a space separator, and convert the first element to float:

```
split_line = line.split(" ")
data_float = float(split_line[0])
```

Notice that if the first element isn't a float number, then `float()` raises a `ValueError` that needs to be handled